# MDX calculated member error

Tags: mdx, data-warehouse, mondrian

How can make a calculated member ? I get this error `Mondrian Error:Member expression 'Filter(Descendants([User].[User Name].Members), ([User].[User Name].CurrentMember.Properties("location") = 'foo'))` must not be a set

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[some users] AS
Filter(
  Descendants([User].[User Name].Members), 
  [User].[User Name].CurrentMember.Properties("location") = 'foo'
 )  
)

SELECT
 NON EMPTY {[Measures].[some users]} ON COLUMNS,
 NON EMPTY CrossJoin(
   [Date].[Date].Members, 
   [Customer].[Customer Name].Members
  ) ON ROWS

FROM [Users]
```

Comment: What do you want to see in your final report? Several users as separate columns? Or a single column value calculated from all users fulfilling the filter criteria? In the latter case, what should be calculated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FILTER` returns a `SET` and you've tried to assign it to a `MEMBER` in the `WITH` clause.

This should work but no measure is specified so you'll get the default measure:

```
SELECT
 NON EMPTY 
{Filter(
  Descendants([User].[User Name].Members), 
  [User].[User Name].CurrentMember.Properties("location") = 'foo'
 ) } 
ON COLUMNS,
 NON EMPTY CrossJoin(
   [Date].[Date].Members, 
   [Customer].[Customer Name].Members
  ) ON ROWS

FROM [Users];
```

You could decide on a measure in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT
 NON EMPTY 
{Filter(
  Descendants([User].[User Name].Members), 
  [User].[User Name].CurrentMember.Properties("location") = 'foo'
 ) } 
ON COLUMNS,
 NON EMPTY CrossJoin(
   [Date].[Date].Members, 
   [Customer].[Customer Name].Members
  ) ON ROWS

FROM [Users]
WHERE [Measures].[aMeasureThatFitsContext];
```

Example of using `RANK`. Just a bit unsure how this fits in with you original script?

```
WITH 
  SET [myFilteredSet] AS 
    Filter(
      Descendants([User].[User Name].Members), 
      [User].[User Name].CurrentMember.Properties("location") = 'foo'
    )
  MEMBER [Measures].[userRank] AS
    RANK(
      [User].[User Name].CURRENTMEMBER,
      [myFilteredSet],
      [Measures].[EXISTING_MEASURE] //<<this is the measure you are ordering by  
    ) 
SELECT
 NON EMPTY 
   {[Measures].[EXISTING_MEASURE],[Measures].[userRank] } 
 ON COLUMNS,
 NON EMPTY 
   [myFilteredSet] 
 ON ROWS
FROM [Users]
```

Comment: thank you for that insight. But how can I apply the `Rank` function to the returned members?

Comment: I intend to retrieve some members based on the filter and then rank the members according to a measure

Comment: feed the filtered set into the Rank function - I'll add an attempt